# What is FunctionDeclarations returns? [bug?]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I did 2 examples for demonstrate my question:

```
/// first script
function a(){}
/// Outputs: undefined
```

---

```
/// second script
{
   function a(){}
}
/// Outputs: f a(){}
```

You can run both examples in chrome dev-tools.
Now let's look at specification:

> **14.1.21 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation**
>
> *FunctionDeclaration: functionBindingIdentifier(FormalParameters){FunctionBody}*
>
> 1. Return NormalCompletion(empty).
>
> `NOTE 1 An alternative semantics is provided in B.3.3.`
>
> *FunctionDeclaration: function(FormalParameters){FunctionBody}*
>
> 1. Return NormalCompletion(empty).

So you can see FunctionDeclaration must return `Completion([[Value]]: empty)`

Is the chrome dev-tools lying?

P.S Firefox in second example `outputs: undefined`

Comment: Reported in https://crbug.com/843034

Comment: @wOxxOm good. Note: in strict mode, I get "use strict", what says: value of block is empty and value from string "use strict". Together will be not empty value - "use strict"